# Create a file C++ (cross-platform solution for Unix and Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, file, unix, cross-platform

Is there a way from C++ code to use (fstream, FILE, etc.) to *create* a file on both Unix and Windows?

If not what you can do in order to have your code run on both Unix and Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ofstream out(path);
```

or

```
FILE *fp = fopen(path, "w");
```

will create the file `path` if it does not exist.

Comment: This will CREATE a file on both unix and windows ?  It will also open it ?

Comment: I know this is old but it's worth mentioning that this fails on Windows if the file name contains UNICODE characters. On (most) Unix systems, it works (just pass the unmodified UTF-8 encoded file name through).

Answer (score 2):

```
fopen("foo.txt", "w"); // write-only
fopen("foo.txt", "w+"); // write+read
fstream filestr;
filestr.open ("foo.txt", fstream::out | fstream::trunc); // write-only
filestr.open ("foo.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc); // write+read
```

All of these will create the file, or truncate it if it already exists.

Comment: I'd add the declaration of `filestr` for clarity.

Comment: This will create the file on both win and unix ? It will also open it ?

Comment: @Roman Dorevich: It will create the file on any platform supporting standard c++